# Collapsible list in html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I'm trying to make a collapsible date selector for our blog. I've looked at a ton of JavaScript/jquery/css examples but I can't seem to get any of them to work well with a 3 level list.
This is the layout I'm trying to accomplish:

```
>2012
  >July
    >title of muh new blag!
```

and here are the tags:

```
<ul class="example_menu">
  <li><a class="expanded">Section A</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link A-A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link A-A-A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link A-A-B</a></li>
     </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Link A-B</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Link A-C</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Link A-D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="footer"><span> </span></li>
  <li><a class="collapsed">Section B</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link B-A</a>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link B-A-A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link B-A-B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link B-A-C</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link B-B</a>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link B-B-A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link B-B-B</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link B-C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link B-D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="footer"><span> </span></li>
  <li><a class="collapsed">Section C</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link C-A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link C-B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link C-C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link C-D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="footer"><span> </span></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to do something as simple as blogspot's blog archive. ([Check it out here on this guy's page](http://wollay.blogspot.com/))

The one I've found and like this most is [this one](http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/collapsible-menu/). And after stripping out a LOT of the extra code, I come out with this:

> $('.example_menu li > .expanded').show('normal');
>
> $('.example_menu li > a').click(function() {
>
> $(this).toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed').parent().find('ul').toggle('normal');
>
> });

This lists expands and contracts and would work great for a simple 2 level list such as:

```
>Year
    >Month
```

However, with a 3 level list it either collapses while expanding the 2 deeper levels or expands both levels. I'm trying to make the immediate lower list to collapse/expand and leave the lowest list collapsed until activated directly.

Are there any simpler jquery collapsible lists?

Or is there a good way to get the immediate interior ul element and toggle that one while turning all other interior ul elements to collapsed?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently I was almost there.

```
//hide everything
$('.outline li > ul').hide();
//activate class "expanded"
$('.outline li > .expanded + ul').show('normal');
$('.outline li > a').click(function() {
//hide everything
$(this).find('ul').hide();
//toggle next ul
$(this).toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed').next('ul').toggle('normal');
});
```